# Return Json from HashMap <String, Object> in Rest API?

Tags: java, json, rest, hashmap

i'm new in java and i'm trying to make a get Rest API . The problem that i can't convert result to Json. This a part of code:

```js
@Path("/")
public class Search{
 @GET
    @Path("/result")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response getAllResults(){
    
        Map<String, DashboardSpaceResult> map = new HashMap<String, DashboardSpaceResult>();
        Map<String, List<Page>> objectsBySpace = SPGSearchUtils.searchAllPagesForLabels(MetaData.GLOSSARY_LETTER, null);    
     
     for (String spaceKey : objectsBySpace.keySet()) {
      
      DashboardSpaceResult glossarySpaceResult = new DashboardSpaceResult();
            Page parentPage = objectsBySpace.get(spaceKey).get(0).getParent();
      
            glossarySpaceResult.setHome(parentPage);
            glossarySpaceResult.setSpace(objectsBySpace.get(spaceKey).get(0).getSpace());
            
            map.put(spaceKey, glossarySpaceResult);
  }
     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(map);
     return Response.ok(jsonObject).build();
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: jsonobject : true jsonarray : false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
return Response.ok(map).build();
```

it should automatically use provider to convert to json

Comment: i got this error : org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class com.samer.api.model.dto.DashboardSpaceResult and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["SS"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:52)

Comment: i changed the class attributes from private to public and it work